# Process table in operating system

Tags: operating-system

Some articles adopt that process table is a collection of all PCB (process control block) while PCB is structure that contains all process information (stack pointer, register set, program counter, etc.) 
And entry of a process will remain in table unit it terminated and its resources deallocated

Until now is right all we know that but are there some cases in which process entry release from table even process still not terminated? 
Such as in case creating  child process , when parent call wait system call , entry of child process should be released from process table because in that case parent can handle exist status of child through wait system call ( function ) , some of articles adopt this concept , I do not know if I misunderstanding , 
Can someone make this concept more clearly for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating academic nonsense in the first paragraph. In the real world PCB = "Process Context Block." That is, the CPU-defined structure that defines the state of the process. An operating system has to maintain a PCB for each process (thread). The operating system had to maintain other structures that define the process as well. There is a chain of structures that define the process beyond the PCB, such as for the virtual memory, privileges, time keeping, and whatever.

Maybe such a system exists (I have not done Linux development) but I have never done OS development on a system that has a single structure that defines a process.

In operating systems, a process started from another can either be a subprocess or a detached process. A subprocess is one that is linked to the process that created it. A detached process is one that is not linked.

If a process has subprocesses, it cannot terminate until all of its subprocesses (children) have been terminated.

Comment: Very reasonable answer , but in case child terminated before parent process then parent invoke wait system call for that child , what will happen ?
how parent know when a child has finish terminated if does not invoke wait system call on that child ?

Comment: That is system dependent but normally, the wait will end.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
`wait` explicitly called in parent.
In this case, when the child terminates, the parent gets its status and the entry of the child is removed from the process table.

Case 2;
`wait` not called explicitly in the parent for the child.
In this case, when the child will terminate, its status will not be reaped by the parent and this child process will become a zombie. In Linux such type of processes are shown as `<defunct>`. The entry of this child (zombie) process will still be there in the process table.

Case 3:
`wait` not called explicitly in the parent for the child, but the child is created as a detached process.
In this case if the child terminates, then its entries will be released from the process table. It will not become zombie.